# History back() Method is not working with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser-history

I've inserted a history back button to a companies intranet page and just noticed, that it is working with Google Chrome, but not with Internet Explorer.

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Zurück</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

Is there any alternative code, which also guarantees a history.back function for Internet Explorer? In my company there are users with various versions of Internet Explorer, starting with version 9 to newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, it should work with Internet Explorer versions newer than 9.

Please check, that you have the previous website in the history of the same tab in the browser.

You can try using:

```
window.history.go(-1);
```